# Cannot read properties of null. In loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```jsx
import React from "react";

function Sum() {
  (varvalue = document.getElementById("thenumber").value), (sum = 0);

  while (value) {
    sum += value % 10;

    value = Math.floor(value / 10);
  }

  var rezultat = document.getElementById("result");

  rezultat.value = sum;

  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" id="thenumber" />
      <br />
      <br />

      <button onclick={Sum}>Calculate</button>
      <br />
      <br />

      <input type="text" readonly="true" id="result" />
    </>
  );
}

export default Sum;
```

I am trying to do sum of given number using loop login but I get this error frequently is any idea to solve this??

Comment: If you're using DOM methods like `getElementById()` in a React app, you're typically doing things incorrectly.

Comment: See https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: i think you need more knowledge on reactjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is your first attempt at a React Js project.
I'm going to try and explain how the compilation is going to happen in this case, but first let me point out that `var value` is declared as `varvalue` and it is assigned the value of an element that has not yet been mounted, which is why `null` exception.

What you want is:

```
function Sum() {
  const addVal = () => {
    var value = document.getElementById("thenumber").value,
      sum = 0;

    while (value) {
      sum += value % 10;

      value = Math.floor(value / 10);
    }

    var rezultat = document.getElementById("result");

    rezultat.value = sum;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="thenumber" />
      <br />
      <br />

      <button onClick={addVal}>Calculate</button>
      <br />
      <br />

      <input type="text" readOnly={true} id="result" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sum;
```

What's happening here is only when the user clicks on calculate, your loop calculation is executed. Also, you need to go through the docs and a few examples.